# How to access json file using axios in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I have the following in my data.json stored in the public folder:

```
[
 {
    "content1": "testing"
 }
]
```

In my Vuex store, I have the following state and mutation:

```
state: {
  contents: []
},
mutations: {
  getContent1(state){
  axios
  .get("data.json")
  .then(response => (state.contents = response.data))
}
```

In my component, I can see my files through ...mapState using the following:

```
<p> {{ contents }} </p>
```

However, if I were to switch to `{{ contents.content1 }}` I cannot see the data on the screen any more. Any tips on what's going on?

Secondly, I wish to change the "content1" data in the json file using axios and I plan on writing it like this:

```
putContent1(state) {
  axios
  .put("data.json")
  .then(response => state.contents = state.newContents))

// however, I am not quire sure the last line on the .then, on whether that is correct or not.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because `contents.content1` doesn’t exist…!? If anything, `contents[0].content1` does.

Comment: I feel so dumb, thank you for the assist!